# f3probe for Mac?

Tags: macos, memory

I'm using [f3](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io), a Linux version of the Windows tool [H2testw](https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539), to test on a Mac the actual capacity of some flash memory I bought. Trouble is that the quicker test, done via [f3probe](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#quick-capacity-tests-with-f3probe), is only available for Linux, so I'm using the standard test, via the GUI [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X), which does a full integrity test with [f3write/f3write](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#testing-performance-with-f3read-f3write) rather than just a total capacity test. Trouble is that the flash I bought is claimed to be 512GB large, so it's taking forever. What are alternative best bets? Running f3probe in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)? Running H2testw through Wine?